invalid response after uploading files to web app from http action of azure logic web app
i am using azure logic app for uploading files to azure webapp, but after uploading the files successfully the returning response seems to be 201 created but the expected response of http action method seems to be 200.
this is the error in the http action method

InvalidProtocolResponse The response to partial content upload request is not valid. The status code returned in the subsequent partial content response is 'Created'. Expected status code is 'OK'.

how to resolve this issue?
i tried adding condition action after http such that if http condition have 201 created response then it will proceed with true branch else false. but it seems that the flow is getting stopped with http action itself with the above error.

You want it to run after failing with 201 Created or you want the action to succeed?

Can you add a screenshot of your workflow with an error?


I tried adding condition action after http such that if http condition have 201 created response then it will proceed with true branch else false. but it seems that the flow is getting stopped with http action itself with the error mentioned above.

You should also change in code view or code of Logic app as below:
Firstly in design:

Then in Code:
In Consumption Plan you will find in Logic app Code view and in Standard plan you will find in
Add failed in runAfter and then save:
"runAfter": {
                    "HTTP": [
                        "Succeeded",
                        "Failed"
                    ]
             }


After Saving, in design it will look like this:

If you have only kept Failed and removed Succeeded, it will show as:

